How to use registered token in ArcGIS JavaScript API
I'm trying to get access to secured ArcGIS resourses with ArcGIS JavaScript API. I'm using IdentityManager.registerToken() and I see that token received. But map opens Log In form anyway.
I expected that if token registered application will use it and doesn't ask token again. Am I wrong and this is not how it works?
Here is my code example:
<script>

  function login(esriId, user, password) {
    var serverInfo = {
      "server": "https://server:port",
      "tokenServiceUrl": "https://server:port/arcgis/tokens/generateToken"
    };
    var userInfo = {
      username: user,
      password: password
    }
    esriId.generateToken(serverInfo, userInfo).then(function (response) {
      response.server = serverInfo.server;
      response.userId = user;
      esriId.registerToken(response);
    });
  }

  require([
    "esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/Basemap", 
    "esri/layers/TileLayer", 
    "esri/views/MapView",

    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",

    "esri/identity/OAuthInfo",
    "esri/identity/IdentityManager",
    "esri/identity/ServerInfo"

  ], function(esriConfig, 
              Map, 
              Basemap,
              TileLayer,
              MapView, 
              FeatureLayer,
              OAuthInfo, 
              esriId,
              ServerInfo) {
    login(esriId, 'test', '123456');
    const arcgisBaseURL = "";
    const arcgisMap = "test";

    const layer = new TileLayer({
        url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"
    });
    const customBasemap = new Basemap({
        baseLayers: [layer],
        title: "My Basemap"
    });
    const map = new Map({
        basemap: customBasemap
    });

    const view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [50, 25],
        zoom: 13
    });

    const myLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: arcgisBaseURL + "/arcgis/rest/services/test/"+arcgisMap+"/FeatureServer/0",
    });
    map.add(myLayer);

  });
</script>


From the URLs in your code, are you using a stand alone GIS Server? or a Portal? If stand-alone, I think you need to use: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/secure-resources/#standalone-arcgis-server

This might help: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/tutorials/implement-user-authentication/

@KHibma I have ArcGIS Server so i guess i can't use OAuthInfo and IdentityManager. So basicaly in this case i don't have any options and esri just forces to buy Portal or ArcGIS Online subscription?

If you're using a standalone ArcGIS Server (No Portal), you won't be able to use oAuth. oAuth and appIds and that authentication mechanism comes from the Portal. I guess it's a matter of perspective if you want to think you're being forced to buy something. When you federated Server to your Portal, you can leverage Portal's authentication (oAuth provider for example), else you're limited to the security mechanisms supported by Server
